# Google seemingly ignoring redirects

Tags: google, google-search-console, redirects, subdomain

So a bit of background. We previously maintained a blog-style news site to supplement our main e-commerce site, on a separate domain, let's call it `magazine.example.com`. The site was built using Wordpress, but we decided to rebuild the site using Sulu (Symfony-based CMS), and move the content into our main website (`example.com/articles`).

All old content has been correctly redirected (301) from its old URL on `magazine.` to the new location on our main site. Anything that we didn't migrate across is sending a `410 Gone` response.

We have now discovered that, 6 months since the move, Google seems to be holding on to the legacy URL In SERPs, showing the legacy `magazine.` subdomain URL, but clicking on the result correctly loads the redirected page. Any new material that is posted to the Sulu blog is correctly being indexed and showing the correct URL in SERPs, but any old articles that have been migrated across still seem to be holding on to the `magazine.` subdomain for some reason. I'd have expected after 6 months that Google would have been intelligent enough to update those entries.

What's even stranger, when we use the `Fetch as Google` from within Search Console for one of the legacy pages (let's say `magazine.example.com/article.html`), they're showing the 301 redirect as working, and the user-defined canonical URL as correct (i.e. `example.com/articles/article`), but the entry in the SERP is still showing the legacy domain.

Has anyone encountered this before, and have any suggestions for a possible fix? Here's a list of what we've tried:

1. Verify redirects and `410 Gone` responses on `magazine.example.com` are valid and working (they are).
2. Ensure a valid sitemap is submitted to Google for `example.com/articles/sitemap.xml`
3. Verify that each post's canonical URL is set correctly (i.e. to the `example.com/articles` URL) - it is.
4. Move Google Search Console property for old `magazine.` site into the main Search Console property for our domain.